# bitly gives HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to build a short url using bitly.
I am doing it in template with a template filter like this.

```
{{long_url|shorten_url}}
```

where shorten url is like this:

```
@register.filter(name='shorten_url')
def shorten_url(value):
    username = settings.BITLY_USERNAME
    password = settings.BITLY_PASSWORD
    bitly_url = "http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login={0}&apiKey={1}&longUrl={2}&format=txt"
    req_url = bitly_url.format(username, password, 'https://'+ value)
    short_url = urlopen(req_url).read()
    return short_url
```

error trace back is like this.

```
    short_url = urlopen(req_url).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

it was working previously, but unexpectedly broken.
Trying to put that `short_url = urlopen(req_url).read()` and catching the exception says, INVALID_URI, Please help me debug this issue.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are passing in as `value`?

Comment: maybe something went wrong on Bitly's side thats what the error messgage tells - 500. Either way sharing what you are sending as the value might help.